# I am attempting to make a ticker with css

Tags: css, flexbox, ticker

I am attempting to make a ticker css similar to [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ERaeC.png)

What I am looking for is to make the ticker shorten names with ellipses that are over a certain length and cutoff the last name.

My current problem is that it does not cutoff the names and just shortens them all with ellipses to fit in the div. I am not sure why this happening as I am using flex-box: nowrap.

My current code:

```css
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
  background-color: #231C18;
}

body {
  -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
}

.content {
  flex: 1;
  flex-grow: 1;
  flex-shrink: 1;
  flex-basis: 0%;
  overflow: auto;
  width: 100%;
  align-self: center;
  display: block;
}

.container {
  background-color: #1A1411;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  overflow: hidden;
  margin: 0 auto;
  flex: 1;
  padding: 15px 25px 0 25px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 300px;
  align-self: center;
}

.ticker {
  background-color: #342E29;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  flex-wrap: nowrap;
  overflow: hidden;
  height: 20px;
  margin-top: 12px;
}

.item {
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  max-width: 75px;
  margin-left: 5px;
  margin-right: 5px;
}
```

```html
<div class="content">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="ticker" id="ticker">
      <div class="item">
        first item
      </div>
      <div class="item">
        very long item
      </div>
      <div class="item">
        third item
      </div>
      <div class="item">
        forth item
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Thanks

Comment: For the last item can you use `.item:last-child {text-overflow: clip}`?

Comment: Thnak you! I didn't know that existed.